# How do I change the color of variables in for-loop declarations in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, color-scheme

I can change the colors of other types of code, including other types of variables, but I don't know the specific name of the variable that appears in for-loop declarations, and I can't find a for-loop in the example code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // do something
}
```

How can I change the color of the `i` that appears here in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: I do not think it is possible. You can file request for new feature here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Editor > Color Scheme > Language Defaults`

Then, the only type that the `i` in a for loop falls under is `Identifiers > Reassigned Local Variable`. Problem is, this changes any local variable that's reassigned, so **not feasible**.

The only way you're getting this to happen is by submitting a [usability request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA)... sorry.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov I know, I never said it was a good idea, I'm only showing the OP the way it can be done. I have edited the answer to clearly show that this is not a good idea.